# How to make sure button click animations are shown when event raised via code?

Tags: c#, xaml, button, click, windows-phone-8

I have defined different background images for the normal and pressed button state via XAML and they are being shown properly when the button is clicked manually.

However when raising the click event using the following code, the background stays at the normal state.

```
btnClick_Click(this.btnClick, EventArgs.Empty);
```

The button click event

```
    void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       .... 
    }
```

How to make sure the normal/pressed background is shown?

Comment: `when raising the click event using the following code` - you're not raising the event, you're just executing a method. Its got nothing to do with the event itself.

Comment: OK so how do I raise the event correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In case anyone wondering, here's how what I've done.

Instead of raising the click event, I work with the VisualStateManager to change the button normal/pressed appearance:

```
    private void changeButtonState()
    {
        if (_isPressed)
        {
            _state = "Pressed";
            _isPressed = false;
        }
        else
        {
            _state = "Normal";
            _isPressed = true;
        }

        VisualStateManager.GoToState(btnClick, _state, true);
    }
```